# Probability using combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

If Sapphira randomly chooses a 4-digit number (not beginning with zero) what is
the probability that all four digits will be distinct?

Let $$x = abcd$$ where they are digits.

Lets see first how many ways there are to choose a digit. The answer is:

$$10^3(9) = 9000 \space \mathrm{ways}$$

But how do I get the $\binom{a}{b}$ for distinct numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The total number of ways to choose a $4$-digit number not starting with $0$ is $9\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10=9000$.

The number of ways to choose a $4$-distinct-digit number not starting with $0$ is $9\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7=4536$.

So the probability of choosing a $4$-distinct-digit number not starting with $0$ is $\frac{4536}{9000}=50.4\%$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\c}[2]{^{#1}{\rm C}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\d}[1]{{\rm #1}}
\d P=\frac{\c{10}44!-\c933!}{9*10^3}=50.4\%\text{ exactly}$$
Total numbers: $9*10^3$ as you said.

$\text{4 digit numbers with distinct digits (not beginning with zero)}= \text{4 digit numbers with distinct digits} - \text{4 digit numbers with distinct digits (beginning with zero)}$

### 4 digit numbers with distinct digits

i.e. $\c{10}44!$ as number of digit in {0,1,2,..9} are 10.Choose 4-Arrange 4

### 4 digit numbers with distinct digits (beginning with zero)

$\c933!$ for $0.\_.\_.\_$ and as number of digit in {1,2,3..9} is 9. Choose 3-Arrange 3